# If i scale down parts of my UV unwrap, how can I make the rest utilize the new space?

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

For example I have a building to unwrap, i use smart uv project and in the resulting uv map the UV Island for the roof is too large and I can scale it down. after scaling it down how can I make the rest fill up the newly created space? I tried using the "pin" option on the scaled down roof uv island, then clicked smart uv project again, but that doesn't work. Is there any way to automatically make it fill up the new space?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

So you want to arrange UV islands within the UV space.

1. Select the UV islands you want to arrange
2. Go *UV > Pack Islands*
3. Done

[image]

Comment: Thank you, thats exactly the feature i was looking for and missed somehow!

However I have one issue with it: I don't know how to make it respect shared uv islands.. 
for example i have 4 wheels of a car i stack the uv islands on top of each other and when i pack the islands to use the new space they will be separated again. I also tried packing the islands with only one of the four wheels selected which absically works but it scales up the wheel island size and i don't know how to make the 3 others fit on top of it because they now have different scaling. i hope you understand what i mean.

Comment: Hello :). To perfectly match the wheel scale, you can use the Texel Density Checker addon. It is free and frankly invaluable for cases like these :).